# C# Visual - Datagridview search if textbox = cell string

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to make it so that when you enter data into `DataGridView` it first checks
if the ID textbox contains a string that exists in the `DataGridView` ID column and throws an error if it finds a match.

If it does not match then the system can add the data.

I tried all kind of codes that people posted nothing worked.
here is my latest.

```
private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label label25 = new Label();

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == IDtxtbox.Text)
        {
            label25.Text = "ID was already created,try some other number";
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(IDtxtbox.Text, Nametxtbox.Text);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have any idea where it fails?

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing works". Are you getting any errors ?

Comment: And I see that you create a new `label25`, but you dont add it to your form like: `this.Controls.Add(label25);` Hence the label won't show up on the form. Ideally there should already be a label on your form and you should just change the label text and not create a label every time the `btnadd` is clicked !

Comment: In the above code if the first row doesn't contain the value, you are adding the value.

Comment: @Marshal leave that,its a typo. just added it to show an example of what i would do if the ID text box is the same.

Comment: @gilmishal 
You probbably do not know how to read hebrew so I'll tell you what it says.
it says that I'm directing myself to an object that has not been created

Comment: @RezaAghaei
How do I do so it checks every possible existing ID?.
Maybe for loop?

Comment: Check the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

In the above code if the first row doesn't contain the value, you are adding the value.

You can check it this way:

```
var exists= dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                         .Where(row => !row.IsNewRow)
                         .Select(row => row.Cells[0].Value.ToString())
                         .Any(x => this.IDtxtbox.Text == x);

if(!exists)
{
    //Add rows here
}
```

Don't forget to add `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 0):

Reza's answer is perfect if you were to use Linq, but if you are new to Linq and need a simpler solution here you go:

Idea is to check all the rows if that contains the ID. If any of the row has that ID, `hasDuplicate` turns true. After checking all the rows (`foreach` loop), then you should decide what to do (`if-else` statements): like to display a message(`label25.Text`) or add a new row(`dataGridView1.Rows.Add`).

```
    private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        bool hasDuplicate=false;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[0] !=null && row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == IDtxtbox.Text)
            { 
                hasDuplicate = true; 
                break;
            }                   
         }

         if(hasDuplicate)
             label25.Text = "ID was already created,try some other number";

          else   
          {
             label25.Text.Clear();                
             dataGridView1.Rows.Add(IDtxtbox.Text, Nametxtbox.Text);
          }

    }
```

Comment: You say you have the same problem..but what problem you have? Does it throw an error ?

Comment: Yes it does. Throws an error that says you can't direct an object that is not created

Comment: Did you check the edit I made. Can u please specify on what kine it throws an error ?