# Difference between null and not null in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am developing an application in asp.net, where I need to find Text-Box control from the Grid row, which I already found by using type-casting to Text-Box variable, and now I am confused that, should I check if Text-Box is null then return from that line or if Text-Box is not null then go forward.

Comment: please see link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34550214/c-sharp-visual-datagridview-search-if-textbox-cell-string

Answer (score 0):

Check if textbox is not null, then do your work.  Otherwise allow the code to exit without any other effort.

Comment: Thanks, Frank! for guiding me